# Android Firebase Messaging calling getToken too soon after starting service?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-service

I think I designed my use of Firebase Messaging in my Android app in a way that recently caused a problem.

When a user indicates he wants to receive messages, I then start my FirebaseMessagingService and immediately go get the token in my Activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, myFirebaseMessagingService.class);
startService(i);

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            // send token to server...
```

A large number of devices recently did not get a token the first time using this method. The second time the user went to this Activity, the service was already running, so the devices got their token successfully using the same method.

Am I right that the token isn't generated the first time because I'm calling getToken() too soon after starting the service? (I have not been able to reproduce this while debugging.)

If so, I'm thinking the solution is to just start the service when the app is launched, so that by the time the user gets to this Activity, the token can be obtained successfully.

(Another possibility is that the service fails to start the first time but does start the second time, but I'm not sure why or how to detect that.)

Note the app is using Firebase Messaging version 22.0.0. I need to update it, of course, but I'm not sure the latest version solves this problem.

Comment: you don't need to start firebasemessaging service manually. Just register it in manifest. Now, first Initialise firebase app in Application class and then get token in application only.

Answer (score 0):

In MainActivity, you are calling getToken() before the service is started. The service is started asynchronously, so it's possible that the service is not started when getToken() is called. You can try to call getToken() in the onServiceConnected() callback of the service connection. Try in your MainActivity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, myFirebaseMessagingService.class);
startService(i);

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // send token to server...
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
    }
};

bindService(i, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already calling the getToken() immediately after starting the service with startService(), just not in the MainActivity. Why did it fail for a lot of phones one day when it had worked fine before?

Comment: I'm trying to find out. test and let me know if it doesn't work. so we can think of other possibilities.

Comment: Hi @tibic4. I went ahead an awarded the points to you since time was about to expire. Thanks for your help in determining why tokens weren't generated with the existing code. Further diagnosis is also appreciated! I've changed the code to auto-start the service with the application, so I'm hoping that prevents future issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious to know that why are you initialising service this way?
You can declare your service in AndroidManfiest.xml with  tag and add filter as:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />                </intent-filter>
```

That's it! Your messaging service will start working.
Also you can get FCM token with the above code with no issues.
PS. Try to update the SDK to have latest implementations.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I will do. Previously, I only started the service (and immediately got the device token) only if the user wanted to receive notifications. That sequence seemed to not always work, and I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: In case you don't want user to get notifications (if they opted-out) then you just need to write a logic to not send notification to that user. You can do so in two ways. 
- Send a bogus token to the backend server or any third party you are using to receive notifications.
- Add a check in onMessageReceived() method of FCM service that if user don't want to get notification just ignore the message.
I would suggest to go for approach 1. Also not to register/start service is not a good option as service handling is already done by firebase so no need to do same again.

Comment: Thanks Malik. Option 1 is essentially what I'll do: not send a token to my server even if the token is generated by Firebase Messaging.

Comment: Cool man! Would you like to mark my answer as correct answer if it's gonna help you in any case?